# getting an error while uploading the file

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to upload a 305968 kb file, I keep getting an error that file is too big, maximum file size exceeded. I did the below changes in web.config file , but I keep getting an error

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"
executionTimeout="7200" maxRequestLength="102400" minFreeThreads="88"
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="76" appRequestQueueLimit="200"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

I also made this change in web.config file

```
<security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxQueryString="10000"
maxUrl="10000" maxAllowedContentLength="3072000000"></requestLimits>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this..

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"
executionTimeout="7200" maxRequestLength="409600" minFreeThreads="88"
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="76" appRequestQueueLimit="200"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

`Your maxRequestLength is smaller then the file size you are trying to upload.` Keep in mind [**maxRequestLength**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) default unit is kilo bytes not mega bytes. Your file size is 203568 kile bytes larger than the allowed limit in the web.config. Increase the maxRequestLength = "409600" or event greater to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `maxRequestLength` which is in KB(default unit)

`maxRequestLength` indicates the maximum request size supported by `ASP.NET`, whereas `maxAllowedContentLength` specifies the maximum length of content in a request supported by `IIS`. So you need to set both in order to upload large files: the smaller one "takes priority".

Comment: But 3000000KB is greater than uploaded file size (305968 KB)

Comment: sorry ...my bad ...the error is due to maxRequestLength is only 102400KB